# Time series prediction problem formatted correctly for LSTM neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, predictive-models, lstm, hyperparameter

I am new to machine learning, I am trying to find a way to predict voltage waveforms into the future. I have seen examples that successfully predict sinusoids or continuous voltage data based on timeseries. (following the same idea)

My data set looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Each sequence maps one discharge cycle of a specific sensor (padded to 1000 data points).
My goal is now to train a LSTM network with this data to predict the future course of a curve at any point in time.

The idea is to divide the time series into time windows of 24H. On the basis of these 24H one time step into the future shall be predicted. (Later I would like to put the prediction at the end of the time window as if it had actually happened and based on this a new one)
X_train.shape (3975, 24, 5)
y_train.shape (3975, 1)

When I train the network this way, sometimes I get a model that works very well, and sometimes after training with exactly the same data on the same Model and hyperparameters, I get a model that makes worse predictions, e.g. when the curve rises instead of falls (Completely different, not explainable to me).

Is this a problem with my model setup, data preparation, or is it just too little data to train a model properly?

My basic question is: Is the idea fundamentally wrong for this Dataset?

I'm grateful for any kind of feedback!

Comment: it seems that your data is highly periodic. have you considered classical approaches before going into lstm?

Comment: What are the classical approaches? I have considered ARIMA, it drops out because the data is not stationary in nature. They have a high periodicity because they are 4 different voltage curves from 2 different sensors. The goal is to learn from different curves in order to be able to predict the course of a current voltage curve of a sensor. Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: I am no expert in deep learning, I do not want to get you in the wrong direction. But to my knowledge, you can at least try a harmonic regression approach, which I found to be very effective in a dataset similar to yours. You can check the following link: https://otexts.com/fpp2/dhr.html
I also suggest you add another plot of your dataset showing your series in long run so that others can provide a better answer by investigating possible patterns.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but I think it is not seasonality in my dataset, but sequences?